# Explaining how to remove a bootstrap-card in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, handler

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FriendCard from "./components/FriendCard";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper";
import Title from "./components/Title";
import friends from "./friends.json";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  // Setting this.state.friends to the friends json array
  state = {
    friends
  };

  removeFriend = id => {
    // Filter this.state.friends for friends with an id not equal to the id being removed
    const friends = this.state.friends.filter(friend => friend.id !== id);
    // Set this.state.friends equal to the new friends array
    this.setState({ friends });
  };

  // Map over this.state.friends and render a FriendCard component for each friend object
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>Friends List</Title>
        {this.state.friends.map(friend => (
          <FriendCard
            removeFriend={this.removeFriend}
            id={friend.id}
            key={friend.id}
            name={friend.name}
            image={friend.image}
            occupation={friend.occupation}
            location={friend.location}
          />
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The code snippet below allows me to click on a `card` (bootstrap-css) and delete the `card`. It works! But my logical thinking or approach is `on click, delete this card` . I don't see that in this code but it works. I'm not coming from a programming background.

I hope some one can explain it to me and make sense of it in laymens term if you suppose. And maybe direct me me to a few more examples.  Thanks in advance.

```
 removeFriend = id => {

    const friends = this.state.friends.filter(friend => friend.id !== 
id);
     this.setState({ friends });
  };
```

And the totality down below:

Heres the Friend Component:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./FriendCard.css";

const FriendCard = props => (
  <div className="card">
    <div className="img-container">
      <img alt={props.name} src={props.image} />
    </div>
    <div className="content">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <strong>Name:</strong> {props.name}
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Occupation:</strong> {props.occupation}
        </li>
        <li>
          <strong>Location:</strong> {props.location}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span onClick={() => props.removeFriend(props.id)} className="remove">
      
    </span>
  </div>
);

export default FriendCard;
```

Comment: This code filters the friends array taking all friends except those who has their id equals the provided id. Then, it updates the state with the new array of friends.

Comment: Please never use screenshots of code. Please share the code directly in your question. In general, questions need to have code that anyone can use to easily recreate the problem so that we can answer questions.

Comment: ok Tad ill edit this

Comment: You are using a `props` `removeFriend={this.removeFriend}`

Comment: If you show us the code of `components/FriendCard` you can check that they call the parent event via props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the part you have posted here

```
removeFriend = id => {
  const friends = this.state.friends.filter(friend => friend.id !== id);
  this.setState({ friends });
};
```

is the last part of your *logical thinking* **delete this card**

It is the function which is invoked on click, but is not handling the actual clicking.
It takes an id as input and and set your friends state as all elements which matches the given id.
This is done by the filter function which you can read more about here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

The next part of your *logical thinking* **on click** is handled in the FriendCard component

In your App component this line injects your handler function into the FriendsCard component as a property

```
removeFriends={this.removeFriends}
```

This means that your removeFriends function will be called by the FriendCard component whenever it is clicked.

The actual click handling is done in your FriendCard component on this line

```
<span onClick={() => props.removeFriend(props.id)} className="remove">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is uncomplete. To actually understand it you need to look into what happens inside the `<FriendCard>` Component. Then you will notice that the logic probably actually works like you imagine.

You see that the `FriendCard` Component is imported on line 2. It is than referenced inside the `render` function that begins on line 22.

The `App` Component has a state object which contains a `friends` property. For each of those friends that are inside the state object we render a `FriendCard` component by iterating with the map method over the state in line 27. [You can read more over the map method here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

We pass a couple of properties to the `FriendCard` component. One of the property we pass to the `FriendCard` Component is the method `removeFriend` defined in line 14.

This `removeFriend` method is actually responsible for removing a friend from our `state` object. As you see it receives an `id` argument and filters the `state` object for all friends that have a different `id` than the one we passed in (esentially removing the id we are passing to the method).

That `removeFriend` method is likely binded to a `click` handler inside the `FriendCard` Component and invoked once we click on it.

Comment: I added it Snowball -

Answer (score 0):

Both above answers are correct. I would just also add that when update the state property using this.setState function, this triggers React to call your component's render function which will re-render your friend's list based on your new state property (i..e filtered friends list).